# How to give the Apache group write access to log files, and an FTP user read-only access

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, permissions, ftp, user-permissions

Ubuntu 11.10 server

I have a user `bob` who's home directory is `/home/sites/bob`. In that there are directories `public_html` and `logs`.

Apache runs under the `www-data` user. `bob`'s primary group is `www-data`. Apache updates the `access.log` and `error.log` in the `logs` directory. The two log files are owned by `root:root` and have permission `644`.

The `bob` user logs in to an FTP server which works. The problem is `bob` can delete or overwrite the two log files. I need Apache to be able to write to the logs, and for `bob` to only have read access - no overwriting or deleting the logs. How can this be done?

What I've tried:

```
cd /home/sites/bob
chown www-data:www-data logs
chmod 644 logs
```

I expected this to work because it should give Apache write access and the `www-data` group (i.e the `bob` user) just read access. What actually happens is in the FTP session `bob` can see `logs` in the directory list but he can't open it up, when he tries to change to `logs`, the error is:

> Command:  CWD logs
>   Response: 550 logs: No such file or directory
>   Error:    Failed to retrieve directory listing

So my question is how can I give write access to Apache (`www-data`) to `logs` but only read access (and no delete) to `bob`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give execute permission on the logs directory, otherwise the user cannot enter the directory.

```
chmod 754 logs/
```

Comment: out of interest, do you know why Apache creates the log files with ownership `root:root`? I expected it to create them as `www-data:www-data`?

Comment: Yes, this is a security measure. It prevents certain attacks. E.g. requesting a non existing page in order to write evil code into the access/error log file, afterwards using a vulnerability in an installed application to include the logfile and execute the code. See also: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html

Comment: Thankyou. Finally can I just ask why do I need the execute permission on the owner and not the group? E.g. why `754` and not `674` because the FTP user is the one that enters the directory and he gains permission through the group not the owner?

Comment: `754` gives execute permission to both the user and group. The user does not necessarily need it in your case (since `www-data` user is part of `www-data` group anyway) but in my opinion the permission is easier to read when also giving it to the user.